# How to wait for dispatch to be completed before selecting from a store. Ngrx related issue

Tags: node.js, angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

How can I wait for a dispatch to be completed before I select from a store. Do not have any luck in Googling? In this case, how do I wait for the dispatch to be done first before selecting from store?

My codes, appreciate the help supported.

```
**team-list.component.ts**

 teamsState: Observable<{teams: Team[]}>;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromApp.AppState>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new TeamActions.GetTeams({
      search: this.search,
      limit: this.limit,
      skip: this.skip,
      sortBy: this.sortBy
    }));
    this.teamsState = this.store.select('teams');
  }
```

```
**team-list.component.html**

<mat-expansion-panel
    *ngFor="let team of (teamsState | async).teams; let i = index">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-1">{‌{ i+1 }}</div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
              <div class="post-image">
                <img [src]="imageUrl+team.imagePath" [alt]="team.name" style>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-10"> {‌{ team.name }} </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

```
effects
@Effect() // If you do not want to dispatch any actions, if need to modify store state then remove
    teamList = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(TeamActions.GET_TEAMS),
            map((action: TeamActions.GetTeams) => {
              return action.payload;
            }),
            switchMap((params: {search: string, limit: number, skip: number, sortBy: string}) => {
                return this.httpClient.get<Team[]>(
                  `${BACKEND_URL}?search=${params.search}&&limit=${params.limit}&&skip=${params.skip}&&sortBy=${params.sortBy}`);
            }),
            map((teams: Team[]) => {
                return {
                    type: TeamActions.SET_TEAMS,
                    payload: teams
                };
            }),
            catchError((err, caught) => {
              // console.log(err.error.errors);
              this.snackBarService.showSnackBar('Unable to Get Teams', true);
              return caught;
            })
        );
```

Currently during first load, the dispatching action is not completed yet and when i select item from store. It is currently empty.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't, a dispatch is a fire and forget that you can't wait on.

Luckily this isn't needed because `this.store.select('teams')` is an observable.
This means that if it changes, the observable will be emitted a new value and this will cause your component to re-render.

If the list stays empty, you can check if your state is in fact updated this can be done with [@ngrx/store-devtools](https://ngrx.io/guide/store-devtools). If the state is updated but it doesn't show in the component, make sure you don't modify the state directly, but that you're creating a new reference to the array.

Comment: Hi, Currently when I first load the page, the list is empty as it does not set any state in the store yet but I need to refresh then the items will be in the store.

effects

Comment: Yea the items will be automatically updated on the page when you set your state.
If you first want to load the items and then make the page visible, take a look at guards  -https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/preloading-ngrx-store-route-guards

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to clear the selector just before dispatch and filter the response :

```
fromApp.GetStuff.release();
// the state is now empty
this.store.dispatch(fromApp.FetchMyStuff);
// any previous value has been forgotten. The next defined value is just what you want
this.stuff = this.store.select(fromApp.GetStuff).pipe(
    filter(stuff => !!stuff)
);
```

See https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#resetting-memoized-selectors

Comment: Good solution but in my case .release() function doesn't work. Not sure why... maybe something wrong on NgRx side, using 11.1.1 version.

Answer (score -6):

See if the below works for you.

```
this.store.dispatch(new TeamActions.GetTeams({
      search: this.search,
      limit: this.limit,
      skip: this.skip,
      sortBy: this.sortBy
    }))
    .subscribe(() => {
        this.teamsState = this.store.select('teams');
    });
```

The above is per ngxs state management framework. More @ https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/actions-life-cycle#asynchronous-actions

Comment: `Store.dispatch` returns `void`, you can't subscribe to it.

Comment: The question was about ngrx. The link points to ngxs. Not the same tool.